# Как получить имя пользователя C#

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли как-нибудь получить имя пользователя под которым был произведен вход в систему, если же приложение запускается под другим именем?

Т.е. входит в систему(логинится) пользователь ivanov, запускает мое приложение используя учетные данные(логин и пароль) пользователя petrov. 
Можно ли как-то узнать что в системе именно ivanov.

```
Environment.UserName
```

и

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

дают одинаковый результат - petrov.

Comment: Если оно запущено под админом, то, возможно, шансы есть. Иначе - вряд ли.

Comment: Хм.. А проверить пользователя родительского процесса не подойдёт?

Comment: Думаю, что вариант про пользователя родительского процесса можно рассмотреть. Может примерчик есть? 
Спасибо.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что родительского процесса вообще не будет, но всё же проверить стоит. Поищи по округе пример с процессами через WMI - там вроде можно пользователя достать.

Comment: Как вариант узнать какой путь вернет система к C:\Users\UserName\

Comment: Думаю вернет путь Petrov, ровно так же как и окружение под него создает и логинится под ним.

Comment: И как вы себе это представляете? Запуск приложения от имени другого пользователя, создаёт отдельную пользовательскую сессию и все окружение именно оного.
Единственный вариант здесь - это будет использование WinAPI (и то не факт). А именно, поиск открытых окон, получение процессов с ними ассоциированных, получение пользователя запустившего их.

Comment: возможно дубликат: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c

Comment: С моей точки зрения, в этом нет смысла - если пользователь ivanov может запустить приложение от имени пользователя petrov, то и войти в систему он может от имени этого пользователя.

Comment: @Mirdin, смысл может быть в том, что текущий пользователь не админ, а нужны админские права. Например, админ запускает от своего имени приложение, но оно должно менять не только общие параметры, но и для конкретного пользователя. Неужели ни разу не попадались инсталляторы, которые при установке от другого пользователя криво работали и чтобы нормально поставить приходилось дать текущему пользователю админские права, поставить, затем убрать админские права? Мне вот несколько штук попадалось, когда xp пользовался.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я понимаю когда приложению нужны права определенной роли, но зачем приложению знать, что его запустили под другим пользователем... тут какая то дыра в логике, вам не кажется. Какой смысл определять, под каким пользователем работает система, если все такие "определялки" ломаются входом в систему под другим пользователем.

Comment: @Mirdin, вообще, кажется. Но я лично несколько таких инсталляторов встречал. Они писали одновременно в Program Files и профиль пользователя. Текущего пользователя. И установленная от одного пользователя программа из-под другого падала, поскольку в нём отсутствовало то, что она записала в профиль. Приходилось давать пользователю админские права, запускать инсталлятор, а потом убирать админские права. К счастью, Win7 с UAC избавило меня от этой проблемы. Но вряд ли это поможет тем, у кого реально неадминская учётка.

Comment: @Qwertiy [KO mode on] Криво написанные программы встречаются. В том числе инсталляторы. [KO mode off] :)

Comment: Все проще. Есть система, которая работает удаленно, на торговых точках. И за одним рабочим местом могут работать несколько человек. И вот эти люди договариваются между собой и запускают программу под одним пользователем системы. За месяц перевыполняют план и получают денежный бонус, который потом делят между собой. Поэтому и нужно видеть кто сейчас зашел в систему и под кем запустили приложение. Желание заказчика.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот пример, который получает логин пользователя который зашел в систему.

```
private static string _username;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var p in Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer"))
    {
        _username = GetProcessOwner(p.Id);
    }

    // remove the domain part from the username
    var usernameParts = _username.Split('\\');

    _username = usernameParts[usernameParts.Length - 1];

    Console.WriteLine(_username);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static string GetProcessOwner(int processId)
{
    var query = "Select * From Win32_Process Where ProcessID = " + processId;
    ManagementObjectCollection processList;

    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
    {
        processList = searcher.Get();
    }

    foreach (var mo in processList.OfType<ManagementObject>())
    {
        object[] argList = { string.Empty, string.Empty };
        var returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(mo.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));

        if (returnVal == 0)
        {
            // return DOMAIN\user
            return argList[1] + "\\" + argList[0];
        }
    }

    return "NO OWNER";
}
```

Comment: А что если в систему зашло несколько пользователей? Насколько я понимаю, этот код выдаст случайного, а не текущего.